# How can I get a range of rows in a python list without creating a new list object?

Tags: python, list

I have a large two dimensional list that i treat like a matrix.  Right now I am getting a subset of these lists by doing

```
subset = mainList[startIndex:endIndex]
```

but I belive this makes a new list, and copies all the rows into the new list.  Is there any way I can avoid duplicating the data and just pointing to the rows inside the mainList?  Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you create a new *outer* list, but the nested lists are *not* copied. You are not really copying data, only the *references* to the nested lists are copied over.

That one list object this creates, and the contained references are cheap. Don't worry about those.

A quick illustrative demo:

```
>>> mainList = [['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], ['idle', 'cleese', 'jones']]
>>> sliced = mainList[:2]
>>> sliced
[['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs']]
>>> sliced[0][1] = 'parrot'
>>> mainList
[['foo', 'parrot', 'baz'], ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'], ['idle', 'cleese', 'jones']]
```

Altering the nested list in `sliced` altered the list object shared with `mainList`.